# Typescript Declaration Merging not working across projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

My main goal is to be able to use typings across the Front- and Back-end of my application.
I have already read about references and added them to my tsconfig.json. The problem is that the declaration merging I've made to the Express Response Object is not being recognized by the Front-end and being returned as `any`.

Example:
I have a `dashboard.ts` (controller), that has for now a single function to return the dashboard data.

`dashboard.ts`

```js
import * as userModel from '../entities/user';
import * as modelModel from '../entities/model';

export const getData = async (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
    const model = await modelModel.getActive();
    const availableStaff = await userModel.count();

    return res._json(200, {
        model,
        availableStaff,
    });
};

export type GetDataReturnType = Unpacked<ReturnType<typeof getData>>;
/**
 * Gives me 
 * 
 * type GetDataReturnType = {
    model: Model & {
        committees: (Committee & {
            delegations: Delegation[];
            directors: User[];
        })[];
        registrations: Registration[];
    };
    availableStaff: number;
}
 */
```

Then I export the type `GetDataReturnType`, so the Front-end could use it as well.

Notes:

- I created a `Unpacked` type to get the ReturnType without the `Promise<>`
- The `_json` is the declaration merging I created to the Express.Response Object (code bellow)

`server/src/@types/express/index.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            _json: <T>(status: number, body: T) => T;
        }
    }
}

export {};
```

`res._json` implementation in
`server/src/server.ts`

```js
app.response._json = (status, body) => {
    app.response.status(status).json(body);

    return body;
};
```

On the Back-end, everything works fine.

Nevertheless, when I import `GetDataReturnType` in the Client, the type comes as `any`

`/web/src/hooks/useDashboard.ts`

```js
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { api } from '../services/api';

import type { GetDataReturnType } from '@controller/dashboard'; 
/**
 * Gives me
 * 
 * type GetDataReturnType = any
 */

import * as DateFns from 'date-fns';

const fetchDashboard: QueryFn<GetDataReturnType> = async () => {
    const response = await api.get<GetDataReturnType>('/dashboard');

    return response.data;
};

export const useDashboard = () => {
    const { data: dashboard, status } = useQuery(
        ['dashboard'],
        fetchDashboard,
        {
            staleTime: DateFns.hoursToMilliseconds(5),
        }
    );

    return { dashboard, status };
};
```

Here's my `server/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
        "outDir": "../build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
        "removeComments": true /* Do not emit comments to output. */,

        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
        "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
        "strictBindCallApply": true /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */,
        "noImplicitThis": true /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */,
        "alwaysStrict": true /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */,

        "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
        "paths": {
            "@schemas/*": ["./src/schemas/*"],
            "@server/*": ["./src/*"]
        } /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */,
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
        "composite": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "src/@types/index.d.ts", "src/@types/express/index.d.ts"]
}
```

Here's my `web/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "paths": { "@controller/*": ["../server/src/controller/*"] }
    },
    "references": [{ "path": "../server" }],
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

- `server` and `web` are in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing this question, I realized I forgot to add `"../server/src/@types/**/*"` to the `include` option in `web/tsconfig.json`. Now, it works perfectly.